# nopriv actions not working when not logged in

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, woocommerce, admin-ajax

I'm redoing a client's WP/WooCommerce site and I'm having trouble with `admin-ajax` actions when the customer is not logged in.

I don't believe the `nopriv` actions are being found by the ajax call.

If it matters, the client is using WP 4.9.11.

I'm working off of localhost, non-HTTPS. If I log in to the admin, everything works as it should. However, when I'm logged out, I always get a response of `0` when making a req to `/wp-admin/admin-ajax`.

I believe I am registering my actions correctly; here's the "get cart status" function that I'm using in `functions.php`:

```php
// functions.php

function get_cart() {
  wp_send_json(WC()->cart->get_cart());

  wp_die();
}
add_action('wp_ajax_get_cart', 'get_cart');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_get_cart', 'get_cart');
```

And the jQuery calling it:

```
// cart-actions.js

const url = `${window.SITE_GLOBALS.root}/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php`;

function onDocReady() {
  const request = {
    method: 'GET',
    url,
    data: {
      action: 'nopriv_get_cart',
    },
    dataType: 'json',
    success: cart => updateCartStatus(Object.values(cart)),
    error: err => console.log(err),
  };

  $.ajax(request);
}

$doc.ready(onDocReady);
```

I've tried checking if the the user is logged in before calling `add_action()` in `functions.php`, I've tried hoisting the `add_action()` calls to the top of the file, and I've tried renaming everything just to make sure I didn't have typos going on anywhere.

What am I missing?

Comment: The `action` parameter seems to be wrong. Should be `action: 'get_cart',` instead of `action: 'nopriv_get_cart'`. WordPress will determine whether to trigger `wp_ajax_get_cart` or `wp_ajax_nopriv_get_cart` based on the authentication status of the current visitor.

Comment: Are you getting any error in browser console.?